# Canasta - 2 Players

Tags: canasta

In Online Canasta - I cannot understand how the opponent can
pick up the discard pile before melding.  I have been melding
before taking the top card from the discard pile.  They have
a huge advantage and get all of the good discards before melding.

Would appreciate the answer --thank you

Answer (score 4):

In Canasta (any number of players); you can use the top card of the discard pile as part of your initial meld, but you cannot use the rest. So if you have 2 of a kind in your hand, and your opponent discards a third, you can pick up the pile as long as you meet the requirement for minimum meld points.

Once you have that initial meld, you can immediately meld anything else you want, including anything else that was in the discard pile.